# Unusual Declaration Error

Tags: c++

This seems like a really easy fix, but I can't understand what it's coming from.

Any help fully appreciated!

The following 2 lines of code produce the following errors respectively.

```
vector <spades::player> players(4, player());
vector <spades::card> deck(52,card());

error: 'player' was not declared in this scope
error: 'card' was not declared in this scope
```

Below is my card.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>

#include "card.h"
namespace spades {
card::card()
{
    cardSuit = 0;
    cardNum = 0;
}

card::card(int suit, int number)
{
    cardSuit = suit;
    cardNum = number;
}
}
```

Below is my player.cpp

```
#include <iostream> // Stream declarations
#include <vector> //Vectors used to store deck and players hands
#include <string> //String declarations
#include <algorithm> //Shuffle Method
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>
#include "player.h"
namespace spades {
using namespace std;


player::player() {
    score =0; //total score
    bid = NULL; //bid for that round
    tricksTaken = 0; //score for thast round
    sandBag = 0; //the number of points you win, more than what you bid, every 10th bag = -100
    doubleNil = false;
    for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
        hand.push_back(card());
}

void player::addCard(spades::card b){
    for (int i=0; i<hand.size(); i++){
        //compare card being played to the ones in your hand to search and determine which one to erase
        if((hand.at(i).getCardNum() == 0) &&
            (hand.at(i).getSuit() == 0))
        {
            hand.at(i).setCardNum(b.getCardNum());
            hand.at(i).setSuit(b.getSuit());
            return;
        }
    }
}

void player::removeCard(spades::card a) {
    for (int i=0; i<hand.size(); i++){
        //compare card being played to the ones in your hand to search and determine which one to erase
        if((hand.at(i).getCardNum() == a.getCardNum()) &&
            (hand.at(i).getSuit() == a.getSuit()))
        {
            hand.at(i).setCardNum(0);
            hand.at(i).setSuit(0);
            return;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you include the headers?

Comment: Did you include `cards.h` and `player.h` to source file that produces error?

Comment: Yes, in gameplay.h (where the 2 lines are) player.h is included and in player.h card.h is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is actually complaining about the arguments you pass to vector constructors. You specified `player()` and `card()` in the constructor arguments, while it is obvious that your types are actually named `spades::player` and `spades::card`. You correctly specified the `spades::` part in template parameters. Why did you omit the `spades::` part from the constructor arguments?

It should be

```
vector <spades::player> players(4, spades::player());
vector <spades::card> deck(52, spades::card());
```

It should be noted though that the explicit argument is unnecessary, so you can just do

```
vector <spades::player> players(4);
vector <spades::card> deck(52);
```

and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Also you don't need the

```
    namespace spades {

    }
```

block in player.cpp, only around you class definition in the header file.
Maybe you ment

```
    using namespace spades;
```

Comment: This is completely bogus... if the class `player` is declared in the namespace `spades` when declared in the header, as the example strongly implies, then you need to enclose the implementation of its member functions in `namespace spades`.

Comment: @je4d: Well, it depends. When an entity is already *declared* inside the namespace, it is up to you whether you want to reopen the namespace to *define* that entity. In OP's example the definitions are done as `namespace spades { player::player() { ... } }`. That is OK. Alternatively it could have been done simply as `spades::player::player() { ... }`, i.e. without enclosing the definitions into `namespace spades { ... }`

Comment: @je4d: When I try a simple example of what you suggest with gcc I get this error - test.cpp:12:2: error: ‘base’ was not declared in this scope
.

Comment: @AndreyT: It may be compiler differences but this only works for me in gcc4.7 with class definition in 'namespace whatever { }' and implementation after 'using namespace' or using fully qualified names.  Any other combination give scope errors

Comment: @AndreyT granted, fully qualifying it works too - but my point was that the transformation suggested does nothing to resolve the OP's problem

Comment: @alegalle I suggest you post what you're trying to compile onto ideone or some other pastebin so we can see what's wrong - all version of gcc I can remember have no problems with defining functions in a reopened namespace